# How to make a ball capped screw?

Tags: screw-modifier

I am new to blender and I want to make an object that is a bulbous looking screw merged with a sphere at the top.  I can't seem to get it to work the way I want, because I am having trouble getting the screw to have an edge by which to extrude in such a way that I can then merge a semi-sphere on top of.

As you can see I do not have an ending of my screw that is perpendicular in the z-axis, not only they but it is only half a circle too (by design to get a smooth looking screw) but I believe I will need a complete circle to easily and smoothly merge into my semi-sphere (moved up in this picture, and I know it's a sphere now I left it as such for easier viewing)

[image]

Any help you can provide in achieving my goal would be really appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: you could cut horizontally with a knife (K to activate, Z to cut through, C to cut orthogonally), then extrude up and give your extrusion a spherical shape. But it looks like you have inner faces, you should also fix that because it may cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to start with lower resolution. Like here is use *Circle* with 12 vertices. *Screw* mmodifier with 12 *Steps*, *Screw* 1.73.

Duplicate Circle and use as top sphere, just change Screw to zero.

[image]

I'm not sure how transition should looks like, but you can just use Boolean modifier > Union ...

Before boolean, *Apply* *Screw* modifier, *Merge by Distance* 0.04 small inaccuracy. From top view box-select all center vertices and delete. So you get clean topology. Apply Boolean modifier. Loop select inner screw and mark as Sharp <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> 1. Then add Subsurface modifier, Smooth shading. Under Data properties > Normals > enable Auto Smooth.

[image]

... or probably more natural it will result with upper part of sphere and manually delete unwanted faces and reconnect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great this worked!  After I applied the boolean modifier and the subdivision surface modifier to smooth it out I was left with a small gap in one spot near the sphere and where it meets the spiral, but I was able to remedy this by merging a few vertices. Thanks!